# EmberJS Rendering Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, ember.js, rendering

I have a print button that am using an {{#if}} conditional to show when a box gets expanded. I want the box to be expanded and then show the print icon at the foot of the box. But for some reason it is getting rendered early and shown in line with the collapsed box then put in the right place once the box is fully expanded. Here is my code:

Print Icon Template:

```
{{#if view.showPrintButton}}
<div class="print pull-right">
    <a href="/_layouts/irp/print.html#{{unbound id}}" target="_blank">Print Discussion<i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
</div>
{{/if}}
```

Box template:

```
{{#if permissions.comment}}
<div {{bindAttr class="controller.audienceIsShared:shared view.commentEditorExpanded:expanded   :createComment"}}>
<div class="author-image-container content">
    <a href="#/author/{{unbound Informal.Registry.user.id}}"><img src="{{unbound Informal.Registry.user.pictureUrl}}" class="author-image pull-left" /></a>
</div>
{{#if view.commentEditorExpanded}}
<div class="comment-editor-container content">
    <div class="boxSizingDefault text">
        {{
            view view.commentEditorClass
            disabledBinding="view.commentFormDisabled"
            viewName="commentEditor"
            valueBinding="controller.commentInProgress.initialBody"
            attachmentsBinding="controller.commentInProgress.attachments"
        }}
    </div>
    {{#if controller.audienceIsShared}}
        <div class="contextualMessage">This comment will be seen across business units</div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
{{#if notificationRecipients.length}}
<div class="notificationRecipients small detail">
    <span>These subscribers will be notified of your comment:</span>
        {{#if notificationRecipientsIsExpandable}}
            {{#if view.notificationRecipientsExpanded}}
                {{#with sortedNotificationRecipients}}{{> initials}}{{/with}}
            {{else}}
                {{#with collapsedNotificationRecipients}}{{> initials}}{{/with}}
    <span class="link" {{action "expandNotificationRecipients" target="view"}}>
            , {{collapsedNotificationRecipientsRemainingCount}} more...
    </span>
            {{/if}}
        {{else}}
            {{#with sortedNotificationRecipients}}{{> initials}}{{/with}}
        {{/if}}
</div>
    {{/if}}
```

View:

```
    showPrintButton: function () {           
        return (this.get("expanded") !== false) && !this.get("editorExpanded");
    } .property("expanded", "editorExpanded")
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you recreate the issue in jsbin?

Comment: It's a pretty large application I have with a lot of dynamic components. Not sure it's really possible to get it going in jsbin sorry. 

In essence, I am trying to figure out why it is getting rendered early or how i can delay it. Thanks.

Comment: Well you can probaby set showPrintButton to true in the next run loop like Em.run.next(function() {this.set('showPrintButton ', true);})